# Why do I get this error? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'TimedeltaIndex' and 'relativedelta' when adding two dates

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to create a new column in my data frame by adding 6 months to the date column.

```
df_main['m1'] = df_main['date'] + relativedelta(months=6)
```

df_main['date'] is of the format datetime64[ns]
I tried converting it to timedelta64[ns] still doesn't work.

Example df_main['date'] = 2019-04-01

Comment: There's a faster way. I posted an answer with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead do:

```
df['x'].dt.date + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=6)
```

Or a more long-winded -- and slower -- way:

```
df_main['m1'] = df_main['date'].apply(lambda x: x + relativedelta(months=6))
```